# Can Docker Engine start containers in parallel

Tags: docker

If I have scripts issueing docker run commands in parallel, the docker engine appears to handle these commands in series.  Since runing a minimal container image with "docker run" takes around 100ms to start does this mean issueing commands in parallel to run 1000 containers will take the docker engine 100ms x 1000 = 100 s or nearly 2 minutes?  Is there some reason why the docker engine is serial instead of parallel?  How do people get around this?

Comment: It appears that containerd offers some single host startup speed... https://containerd.tools/?mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiTldGbE1EbG1ORGMzTWpFNSIsInQiOiJBR0dhcVJjbENWYnphdDJzRWhLZGcxWXJZS2dndzJNMThaTXdcL1crWU94Y2dXTVhzK05walJlZmNEcHlISHQyWmJWVWw3ZzdKVjZmODArMmljUFM4eGlLbmJkRmJZanJYbG5wVU1PVDg3S3M9In0%3D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do people get around this?

a/ They don't start 1000 containers at the same time
b/ if they do, they might use a [cluster management system like docker swarm](https://github.com/docker/swarm) to manage the all process
c/ they do run 1000 containers, in advance in order to take into account the starting time.

Truly parallelize `docker run` command could be tricky considering some of those command might depend on other containers to be created/started first (like a `docker run --volumes-from=xxx`)

Comment: Thanks. The use case I am considering for Docker involves replacing a legacy system of binary applications that involves a fair amount of fork exec operations in c code starting new processes on the fly. I am trying to get a feel for the correct seams to incrementally introduce Docker without bogging down the system.

Comment: @Mike could those fork be "grouped" amongst several containers, or do you have to have 1 container for one forked process?

Comment: I think that will be part of the balancing act.  A balance of how much work to do in each container instance.  There is a very nice logical separation when doing work in containers which is a new benefit and I am trying to reconcile the 1 process per container with how much work do we put in a single processes.

Comment: What about a solution that uses Docker as a PaaS.  You could have DockerNDocker where the internal Docker is Parallel and does not use volumes-from?